# Extract only words with apostrophe from text file

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract words with apostrophe from text file. I have a program that extract words that their length are certain amount(in the following program 3) and have apostrophe. However I need the one to consider only and only those words with apostrophe without considering any other conditions.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    String s  = "I want to have a lot of money's when I am older.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z']{3,}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
      words.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(words);
```

Comment: use * instead of {3,}

Comment: `"[a-zA-Z']*'[a-zA-Z']*"`

Comment: Are there cases where words can start with apostrophes? Can there be more than apostrophe in word?

Comment: better xD xD xD, tested, it works fine @khelwood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But you know this of the word:

1. contains chars before the apostrophe
2. apostrophe
3. more char(s)

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*'\\w*");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{2,}'[a-zA-Z]*");
```

With this regex you match words with two or more letters, and apostrophe and optional letter after the apostrophe. You can change the minimum/maximum letters in `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` and in the last part insted of asterisk you can use `{min,max}` to specify precisely

Answer (score 0):

This pattern:

```
"[a-zA-Z']*'[a-zA-Z']*"
```

matches any sequence of letters/apostrophes, containing at least one apostrophe.

Therefore it will match even such things as:

- O'Neill's in "Colonel O'Neill's rifle."
- 'n' in "Fish 'n' chips"